# Why do people tend to say the Kara no Kyoukai anime "does not exist"?

Tags: the-garden-of-sinners, type-moon

It's clear from the anime that it exists. Some of the characters from the main series are there. As close as I can tell, it's just a side series.

So why do hardcore Type-Moon fans say with resolve that *Kara no Kyoukai* is not a Type-Moon anime or that it does not exist to them?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't thinking of Tsukihime? I've never heard this about KnK

Comment: Possibly, I know that my friend and I were discussing it on G+ a while back. I could be wrong?

Comment: Maybe. It's the Tsukihime anime that is deemed to not exist, due to how it cuts out a lot of the best parts of the source material. Also, manfaces.

Comment: @MarkM just want to add that the Tsukihime Anime follows closely to the Arcuied Route, it does cut out a couple of parts but it's more faithful to the route than the Fate/Stay Night Anime following the Fate Route, people just say that the Tsukihime Anime doesn't exists because it's not considered cannon

Comment: Related, since this question was seemingly based on a false premise: [Why is it said that the Tsukihime anime “does not exist”?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/43842/why-is-it-said-that-the-tsukihime-anime-does-not-exist). Googling about this, I didn't find any articles/reviews/forums/debates that mention this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kara no Kyoukai, like other Type-Moon series exist in as part of the same [multi-verse](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Nasuverse). While not in  the same universe as Fate or Tsukihime, they exist as an alternate universe, like Fate/Extra and Fate/kaleid liner. The characters could in theory meet one another... if the circumstances are [deemed right](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Ahnenerbe).

[Canaan](http://myanimelist.net/anime/5356/Canaan), however is not part of the this multiverse.

Comment: Why is Canaan related?

Comment: It's not... It's a Type Moon created work, but not a Nasuverse work.

Comment: Fate/Extra is where characters from Tsukihime, Fate/Stay Night and Kara no Kyoukai all appear. So it's not so much a theory, it happened already. The whole backstory from Fate/Extra also suggests that all three are part of the same exact universe. Not sure why some people insist on calling it a multiverse and getting all defensive about this.

Comment: Believe it or not, it's actually as you assume. For an example Crimson Moon [can't exist](http://completematerial.pbworks.com/w/page/57755439/10th%20Anniversary%20QandA) in the EXTRA-verse, so the events in Tsukihime cannot happen. Arcueid and Ryougi are just guest cameos in the character manifested inside the virtual world that is Moon Cell. They are not actually canon to the EXTRAverse. The Nasuverse is very convoluted, not unlike the Marvel multiverse.

Answer (score 1):

Even if marginally, there is a case to be made that the Fate universe and Kara no Kyoukai's are the same. In Fate's Heaven's Feel path, Shiro is restored through Third Sorcery by binding his soul to a body "left by a famous puppet maker" who "was marked to be sealed [by the Mages Association] and ran away." The anime briefly shows Touko leaving the antique store where Rin and Sakura buy Shiro's new body (1:55).

Answer (score 0):

I think you got the series wrong.

It isn't Kara no Kyoukai, but the Tsukihime anime that gets that treatment. It is a meme among type-moon fans.

The anime called Shingetsutan Tsukihime was a really bad adaptation of its source material, the type moon visual novel of Tsukihime.

The fans were unhappy with the adaptation. So they started acting like the anime doesn't exist. That's the origin of the meme.