# Does "The Garden of Sinners" share the same world with "Fate" series?

Tags: fate-series, the-garden-of-sinners

Looking back at both *The Garden of Sinners* and *Fate* series, I noticed that there are mystic eyes in both series. For example, Rider's Mystic Eyes of petrification revealed *Fate/stay night: Heaven's Feel* and Shiki Ryougi's Mystic Eyes of death perception from *The Garden of Sinners* series).

Do they both share the same world?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do people tend to say the Kara no Kyoukai anime "does not exist"?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4380/why-do-people-tend-to-say-the-kara-no-kyoukai-anime-does-not-exist)

Answer (score -2):

Yes, Kara no Kyoukai, Tsukihime and Fate all take place in the same universe.

Aozaki Touko from Kara no Kyoukai is the sister of Aozaki Aoko from Tsukihime. Ciel from Tsukihime and Kotomine Kirei from Fate are part of the same organization. In Fate/Zero there's a part about Kiritsugus past relating to Dead Apostles (Vampires), that are the same as the ones from Tsukihime.

Ryougi Shiki from Kara no Kyoukai and Tohno Shiki from Tsukihime have the same type of mystic eyes.

In Kara no Kyoukai there's a magus trying to reach the origin/root by using a spiral of sorts. It's described as the main pursuit of all magi. In Fate, the Holy Grail War was designed to reach exactly this origin/root, too.

Here's an even more comprehensive relations chart:
[image]

Comment: The usual interpretation is that they are not in the same universe, but rather are in distinct universes that are part of a common multiverse (usually referred to as the Nasuverse).  You can note on your relations chart that the only path from Tsukihime to FSN is through Zelretch, who is kind of literally the embodiment of dimension/universe hopping.  On FSN's earth there is no, and there never was, an Arcueid or True Ancestors (making the Dead Apostles rather different things).

Comment: Since FSN, and so the Nasuverse, has alternative histories and time travel shenanigans embedded in its canonical lore as well, it's not always clear what the difference is between a very different history that diverged long ago versus a completely new universe.  In FGO there's some crazy business about the "Pruning Theoretical Phenomenon" which basically seems to say that histories that diverge too much from the main line are eliminated, and in other works Zelretch is specifically invoked as a semi-omniscient observer/narrator to make the "this is a separate universe" thing clear.

Comment: That's just splitting hairs on what the meaning of universe is. It's still all the same world, even if there are multiverses involved. Just like Isekai Seikishi Monogatari is part of the Tenchi Muyo universe. Unlike distinct works taking place in our world without any magic added, like Initial D and Minami-ke, for example. Those are from distinct universes, even if technically they take place in the same universe, which is ours. Still, the chance of me or you meeting one of the Minami-ke girls is zero.

Comment: Ryougi Shiki meeting Saber during their own Holy Grail war, however, is quite possible. In fact, Ryougi Shiki does make an appearance as a servant in Fate/Extra.

Comment: That Ryougi Shiki encounter is a very strange one, being a special extra boss that's not really part of the story (so questionably canonical) and is neither Master nor Servant, is essentially the only character in the Nasuverse with a direct connection to the Root, and the grail war there uses a completely different grail and summoning system.  So a good point, but one I'm not sure of what the true point it's making actually is.

Comment: Fate/Extra also features Arcueid as a servant in one of the branching paths of the story. Which ties Fate together with Tsukihime and Tsukihime is already tied to Kara no Kyoukai through the Aozaki sisters.

Comment: The point is just that everything takes place in one big world and characters of the three franchises have relations with each other and can reasonably meet. Which was the question here. It doesn't create weird issues, either, for all of them to be part oft the same world, like Meitantei Conan and Magic Kaitou taking place in the same universe, but Magic Kaitou having a side character that is using real magic, which heavily contradicts Meitantei Conans concept.

Comment: By definition, as it's a multiverse, they can't be the same universe. The only reason Arcueid and Shiki appear in the Extraverse is because of the Moon Cell, not because they are from the same universe. Under normal circumstances, they wouldn't be able to appear in Fateworlds. They are all part of the Nasuverse and share the Root, but aside from that, they can't be considered the same universe, as in Tsukihime based worlds, no Holy Grail War ever happens. True Ancestors aren't even a thing in Fateworlds. But broader concepts such as the basics of Magecraft are shared among universes.

Comment: If you go one step up, all multiverses are part of the same universe or world again, so the distinction isn't that important. The question asked about whether they share the same world, which they do. True Ancestors have to exist in Fate, otherwise Arcueid couldn't have been summoned in Fate/Extra. Even if you want to make the distinctions of parallel universes or whatever, it's still the same overarching world. Characters have met each other. Telling someone asking about this otherwise is just being willfully obtuse.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy same 'metaverse' maybe like in higurashi/umineko?